# Deploying Printer with GPO W2K3R2 - isn't working

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, domain-controller, network-printer

I am trying to deploy a network printer from my DC to my users.
This is what I have done so far:

- Created a GPO: Named: Deploy printer
- login script has: pushprinterconnections.exe
- I have linked that GPO to a test OU that has both a test computer, and another OU with the user that I use to log to that computer.
- Enforced = No
- Link Enabled = Yes
- The security filtering is : Authenticated Users

However, no matter how long I wait after I log to the test machine, the printer is NOT getting deployed.

What am I missing in the procedure please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Real good run down](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722179%28WS.10%29.aspx):

**To install printers to groups of users or computers by using Group Policy**

1.
Open the Administrative Tools folder, and then double-click **Print Management**.

2.
In the Print Management tree, under the appropriate print server, click **Printers**.

3.
In the results pane, right-click the printer you want to deploy, and then click **Deploy with Group Policy**.

4.
In the **Deploy with Group Policy** dialog box, click **Browse**, and then choose a Group Policy object.

5.
Click **OK**.

6.
To assign the printer connection setting to the GPO, do one or both of the following:
 As a per-user setting, select the **The users that this GPO applies to (per user)** check box.

As a per-machine setting, select the **The computers that this GPO applies to (per machine)** check box.

7.
Click **Add**.

8.
Repeat steps 3 to 6 to add the printer connection setting to another GPO.

9.
Click **OK**.

**To use the PushPrinterConnections.exe file**

1.
Using Group Policy Management console (gpmc.msc), right-click the GPO with your printer connections settings, and then click **Edit**.

2.
In the Group Policy Object Editor tree, navigate to one following locations:
 If the printer connections are deployed per-machine, go to **Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)**.

If the printer connections are deployed per-user, go to **User Configuration, Windows Settings, Scripts (Logon/Logoff)**.

3.
Right-click **Startup** or **Logon**, and then click **Properties**.

4.
In the **Logon Properties** or **Startup Properties** dialog box, click **Show Files**.

5.
Copy the PushPrinterConnections.exe file to this location and then close the window.

6.
In the **Logon Properties** or **Startup Properties** dialog box, click **Add**.

7.
Type **PushPrinterConnections.exe** in the **Script Name** box.

8.
If you want to enable logging, type **–log** in the **Script Parameters** box. Log files are written to %windir%\temp\ppcMachine.log (for per-computer connections) and %temp%\ppcUser.log (for per-user connections) on the computer on which the policy is applied.

9.
Click **OK**.

Comment: It seems to work, I am not sure what I did wrong last time, but print your instructions and follow them, seem to have deploy my printer.

Comment: Glad to have helped